# Implement side-scrolling like transitions between scenes

Tags: java, animation, javafx, transition

Because my scenes have a gradient background (that goes from one color to another), I would like to implement side-scrolling like transitions between scenes. 
Currently, my scenes switch abruptly, following this code:

```
private static void setupStage(Parent parentScreen) {
    Stage primaryStage = Main.getPrimaryStage();
    if (primaryStage.getScene() == null){
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(parentScreen));
    } else {
        primaryStage.getScene().setRoot(parentScreen);
    }
}
```

What would be a general approach to refactoring the code and implementing the desired functionality?

Comment: so you want that when the user scrolls for example to right border of one scene then the scene should change immediately or the user should see parts of these two scenes?

Comment: should see parts yes. So there would be a continuous transition between to scenes.

Comment: My idea is to merge them into a scrollpane side by side or  (better) Check for scene transition animations